# trigger a method onclick of view larger map option in google maps ember iframe?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, google-maps

I am developing a cordova application using ionic and angularjs. Using google maps embed API, displaying the map in the application.

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

[image]

On click of *view larger map* option in the infowindow, I would like to call a method.

Is there any way to define that? I have tried using the default class of the *view larger map* option but no luck.

For calling a method with the help of the class of view larger map, i have define a ng-click for this map only after the *view larger map* is appened into the page.

But as i am not displaying the map through js code, i am unable to invoke to map idle events.

So, is there any method that can be triggered on click of *view larger map* option?

If no, i would like to create map using google maps javascript API, if so what is the way to show *View larger map* option in infowindow?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow), `open()` method can be used to open InfoWindow on the given map.

You also have the option add `maxWidth` property in your InfoWindowOptions object specification when using InfoWindow constructor to specify your map's parameter for displaying the info window. As mentioned in [Add an info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add),

> `maxWidth` specifies the maximum width of the info window in pixels. By default, an info window expands to fit its content, and auto-wraps text if the info window fills the map. If you add a `maxWidth` the info window will auto-wrap to enforce the specified width. If it reaches the maximum width and there is vertical room on the screen, the info window may expand vertically.

More information, best practices, tips and code samples in using Info Windows can be found in the documentation.